# Types of heat transfer

Tags: thermodynamics, heat-conduction

I’m having some problems to identify the type of heat transfer involved in a practical experiment I’ve carried out. In my experiment, I heat a metal rod by making water vapor flow inside the rod, then I let it cool down to room temperature.

On the one hand, I think it sounds reasonable to argue that both the heat transfer when heating and cooling occurs by convection, since a flow of moving air is involved (water vapor in the first case, room air in the second case). But at the same time, there is direct contact of hot air/cool air in both cases, especially when heating. So one could think heat transfer occurs by conduction.

Would you say both types of heat transfer are actually involved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on the dimensions and thermal properties (thermal conductivity, density, heat capacity) of the rod.  If the rod wall is very thin and has a high thermal conductivity, then the convective transport to the fluid stream will dominate.  But if the rod wall is very thick and/or has a low thermal conductivity, then the conduction within the rod can be significant also.

Answer (score 0):

When only fluids are involved, then convection. Conduction happens between the material surface and an individual fluid particle, but then that particle is immediately replaced by another and a new convective transfer takes place. This repeating process is what we call convection.